# How can I dampen a tankless water heater’s humming sound?

Tags: water-heater, sound-proofing, tankless

I just moved into our new home. First time with a tankless heater. I notice that whenever we turn on hot water after turning it off the tankless heater makes a humming sound. It seems like this is normal from a few google searches but it is quite audible in our kitchen. The heater is located in the garage one floor below. We can even hear it on the second floor.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Gas or electric? Model number?

Comment: Wait a while and you'll get used to it - it will become normal background noise and you'll know something's wrong when you *don't* hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably hearing 60Hz electrical hum. The way to reduce that is to isolate the unit from cabinetry, walls, and plumbing. Some ideas:

- Mount the unit on rubber isolation blocks
- Connect the unit to nearby pipes with flexible hoses (braided steel mesh)
- Insulate the inside of the cabinet or closet enclosure with sound-reducing panels, foamboard or similar

Comment: It might also be a fan blower running.  Some gas tankless have positive ventilation (many really).

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It is gas not electric. The fan makes the most sense as it seems like it turns on in a timed way immediately after a hot water faucet is turned off.